# Select characters (highlight text) in input on mousedown and mouseup with Blazor Component

Tags: input, components, blazor, highlight, selectedtext

Same thing as Javascript Window.GetSelection. Basically I want to be able to grab the selected text in an html input with Blazor.

```
<input type="text" value="" />
```

So whatever value is written into the input, upon mouse-selection will be stored in a string

```
string mySelectedText { get; set; }
```

So the user will do this:
[image: user select text from input]

and the variable will hold this:

```
mySelectedText = "selection is made";
```

Dom-manipulation should be done with `@on` as shown in [this list](https://blazor-university.com/components/component-events/browser-dom-events/) but i cannot see any `@onSelection` in that list

I have tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60110779/get-the-selected-text-from-an-input-using-blazor) without any success.
The user-event must be mouse-selection of text from input, and the selected text must be stored or showed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the selected text from an input using Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60110779/get-the-selected-text-from-an-input-using-blazor)

Comment: No, @Quango, unfortunatly not. I tried to copy the code from your linked page to a component. I cannot even see what the code does. In other words i need to see a working example or documentation on the way to select highligthed text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to combine Javascript with Blazor with the `@inject IJSRuntime`

in the Blazor-component:

```
@inject IJSRuntime js            
     <p @onmouseup="@GetSelectedText">Make selection with mouse on here</p>        
     <p>You highlighted: @SelectedText</p>
@code {
    public string SelectedText { get; set; }

    async Task GetSelectedText()
    {
        SelectedText = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("getSelectedText");
    }
}
```

and the javascript funktion named `getSelectedText` in the `wwwroot/html.html` insert this below the webassembly.js

```
<script>
function getSelectedText() {
    return window.getSelection().toString();
}
</script>
```

This solves the problem